# XeLaTeX failing with Microsoft Fonts

Tags: fonts, xetex, xltxtra

I am using XeLaTeX to produce a `\documentclass{report}` and am having problems loading Microsoft fonts.

The Console reports:

> xdvipdfmx:fatal: Cannot proceed without the font:
>   /Library/Fonts/Microsoft/Calisto MT
>
> Output file removed.

I have tried this with various fonts and it always seems to be the Microsoft fonts that fail. Looking into Finder (on Mac) the first thing I notice is that the failing fonts don't have a suffix (e.g. .ttf or .otf), even though the `Hide extension' option is not selected. Looking into Font Book, it appears that these fonts are in fact .ffil format.

I have tried this with `xltxtra` and `fontspec` and get the same result, though the following MWE using `xltxtra` because that's what is in my working document.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont{Calisto MT}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

Edit: to include Log, at Johannes B's request. As follows:

```
    This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=xelatex 2015.10.14)  21 MAR 2016 10:26
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Untitled.tex
(./Untitled.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@chapter=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty
Package: lipsum 2014/07/27 v1.3 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
\c@lips@count=\count88
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xltxtra/xltxtra.sty
Package: xltxtra 2010/09/20 v0.5e Improvements for the "XeLaTeX" format

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
Package: fontspec 2015/03/14 v2.4c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2015/03/01 v5547 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2015/03/01 v5547 L3 programming layer (code) 
L3 Module: l3bootstrap 2015/02/28 v5542 L3 Bootstrap code
L3 Module: l3names 2015/02/24 v5535 L3 Namespace for primitives
L3 Module: l3basics 2015/01/27 v5500 L3 Basic definitions
L3 Module: l3expan 2014/11/27 v5472 L3 Argument expansion
L3 Module: l3tl 2015/01/27 v5500 L3 Token lists
L3 Module: l3str 2015/03/01 v5545 L3 Strings
L3 Module: l3seq 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Sequences and stacks
L3 Module: l3int 2015/02/21 v5529 L3 Integers
\c_max_int=\count89
\l_tmpa_int=\count90
\l_tmpb_int=\count91
\g_tmpa_int=\count92
\g_tmpb_int=\count93
L3 Module: l3quark 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Quarks
L3 Module: l3prg 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Control structures
\g__prg_map_int=\count94
L3 Module: l3clist 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Comma separated lists
L3 Module: l3token 2014/09/15 v5422 L3 Experimental token manipulation
L3 Module: l3prop 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Property lists
L3 Module: l3msg 2015/02/26 v5537 L3 Messages
L3 Module: l3file 2014/08/24 v5369 L3 File and I/O operations
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count95
\l__iow_target_count_int=\count96
\l__iow_current_line_int=\count97
\l__iow_current_word_int=\count98
\l__iow_current_indentation_int=\count99
L3 Module: l3skip 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Dimensions and skips
\c_zero_dim=\dimen103
\c_max_dim=\dimen104
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen105
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen106
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen107
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen108
\c_zero_skip=\skip43
\c_max_skip=\skip44
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip45
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip46
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip47
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip48
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
L3 Module: l3keys 2015/01/27 v5500 L3 Key-value interfaces
\g__keyval_level_int=\count100
\l_keys_choice_int=\count101
L3 Module: l3fp 2014/08/22 v5336 L3 Floating points
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count102
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count103
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count104
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count105
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count106
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count107
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count108
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count109
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count110
L3 Module: l3box 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Experimental boxes
\c_empty_box=\box26
\l_tmpa_box=\box27
\l_tmpb_box=\box28
\g_tmpa_box=\box29
\g_tmpb_box=\box30
L3 Module: l3coffins 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Coffin code layer
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box31
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen109
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen110
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen111
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen112
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen113
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen114
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen115
\c_empty_coffin=\box32
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box33
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box34
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box35
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box36
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box37
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box38
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box39
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen116
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen117
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen118
L3 Module: l3color 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Experimental color support
L3 Module: l3candidates 2015/03/01 v5544 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen119
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen120
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen121
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen122
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen123
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen124
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen125
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen126
\l__box_internal_box=\box40
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen127
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen129
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen130
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen131
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen132
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen133
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3unicode-data.def
File: l3unicode-data.def 2015/03/01 v5544 L3 Unicode data
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3xdvipdfmx.def
File: l3xdvidpfmx.def 2015/03/01 v5544 L3 Experimental driver: xdvipdfmx
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2014/11/25 v5471 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count111
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count112
\l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count113
\l__xparse_processor_int=\count114
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count115
)
\l_fontspec_script_int=\count116
\l_fontspec_language_int=\count117
\l_fontspec_strnum_int=\count118
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen134
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen135
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen136
Variant \tl_gset:cV already defined; not changing it on line 71

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-patches.sty
Package: fontspec-patches 2015/03/14 v2.4c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLa
TeX
LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 49.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \emph on input line 57.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \- on input line 60.
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/redefine-command"
. 
. Redefining command \oldstylenums with sig. 'm' on line 155.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \liningnums with sig. 'm' on line 159.
.................................................
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
Package: fontspec-xetex 2015/03/14 v2.4c Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1enc.def
File: eu1enc.def 2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for EU1+lmr on input line 105.


(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmr.fd
File: eu1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty
File: xunicode.sty 2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many 
other characters in Unicode lower plane

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def
File: t3enc.def 2001/12/31 T3 encoding
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for EU1+lmss on input line 357
.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmss.fd
File: eu1lmss.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
))
\tipaTiiicode=\count119
\tipasavetokens=\toks14
\tipachecktokens=\toks15

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 94.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-def/xetex.def
File: xetex.def 2015/03/25 v4.04 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (TeX Liv
e/RRM/JK)
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen137
\Gin@req@width=\dimen138
))
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \__fontspec_post_arg:w with sig. 'mmO{}' on line 42.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \fontspec with sig. 'om' on line 44.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmainfont with sig. 'om' on line 54.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setsansfont with sig. 'om' on line 64.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmonofont with sig. 'om' on line 74.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathrm with sig. 'om' on line 88.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setboldmathrm with sig. 'om' on line 96.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathsf with sig. 'om' on line 104.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathtt with sig. 'om' on line 112.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontfamily with sig. 'mom' on line 126.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontface with sig. 'mom' on line 141.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \defaultfontfeatures with sig. 't+om' on line 155.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \addfontfeatures with sig. 'm' on line 210.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontfeature with sig. 'mm' on line 221.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newAATfeature with sig. 'mmmm' on line 229.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newopentypefeature with sig. 'mmm' on line 237.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \aliasfontfeature with sig. 'mm' on line 261.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \aliasfontfeatureoption with sig. 'mmm' on line 270.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontscript with sig. 'mm' on line 275.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontlanguage with sig. 'mm' on line 301.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareFontsExtensions with sig. 'm' on line 321.
.................................................
Variant \prop_gput:cnV already defined; not changing it on line 704
Variant \prop_gput:cnx already defined; not changing it on line 705
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count120
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 2232.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 2237.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 2242.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 2247.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/realscripts/realscripts.sty
Package: realscripts 2013/03/18 v0.3c Access OpenType subscripts and superscrip
ts
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \fakesubscript with sig. 'm' on line 19.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \fakesuperscript with sig. 'm' on line 22.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/redefine-command"
. 
. Redefining command \textsubscript with sig. 's' on line 25.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/redefine-command"
. 
. Redefining command \textsuperscript with sig. 's' on line 28.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \realsubscript with sig. 'm' on line 45.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \realsuperscript with sig. 'm' on line 60.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \textsubsuperscript with sig. 'sO{l}mm' on line 138.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \textsupersubscript with sig. 'sO{l}mm' on line 143.
.................................................
\subsupersep=\dimen139
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/metalogo/metalogo.sty
Package: metalogo 2010/05/29 v0.12 Extended TeX logo macros
\xl@everylogo=\toks17
\xl@@everylogo=\toks18
LaTeX Info: Redefining \TeX on input line 193.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \LaTeX on input line 202.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \LaTeXe on input line 219.
)
\xxt@tempbox=\box41
)
\g__file_internal_ior=\read1
.................................................
. fontspec info: "no-scripts"
. 
. Font Calisto MT does not contain any OpenType `Script' information.
.................................................
\g__fontspec_family_CalistoMT_int=\count121
.................................................
. fontspec info: "defining-font"
. 
. Font family 'CalistoMT(0)' created for font 'Calisto MT' with options
. [Ligatures=TeX].
. 
. This font family consists of the following shapes:
. 
. * 'normal' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Calisto MT/AAT:mapping=tex-text;"
. 
. * 'small caps' with NFSS spec.:
. 
. and font adjustment code:
. 
. 
. * 'bold' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Calisto MT/B/AAT:mapping=tex-text;"
. 
. * 'bold small caps' with NFSS spec.:
. 
. and font adjustment code:
. 
. 
. * 'italic' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Calisto MT/I/AAT:mapping=tex-text;"
. 
. * 'small caps' with NFSS spec.:
. 
. and font adjustment code:
. 
. 
. * 'bold italic' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Calisto MT/BI/AAT:mapping=tex-text;"
. 
. * 'bold small caps' with NFSS spec.:
. 
. and font adjustment code:
. 
.................................................

(./Untitled.aux)
\openout1 = `Untitled.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T3/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T3+cmr on input line 7.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd
File: t3cmr.fd 2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
.................................................
. fontspec info: "setup-math"
. 
. Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid this).
.................................................
\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `EU1' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> EU1/CalistoMT(0)/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `EU1' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> EU1/CalistoMT(0)/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  EU1/CalistoMT(0)/m/n --> EU1/CalistoMT(0)/m/n on input 
line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> EU1/CalistoMT(0)/m/it on input line 7.

LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> EU1/CalistoMT(0)/bx/n on input line 7.

LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> EU1/lmss/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> EU1/lmtt/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  EU1/CalistoMT(0)/m/n --> EU1/CalistoMT(0)/bx/n on input
 line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> EU1/CalistoMT(0)/bx/it on input line 
7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> EU1/lmss/bx/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> EU1/lmtt/bx/n on input line 7.

[1

] (./Untitled.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 13492 strings out of 493706
 283666 string characters out of 6145768
 406167 words of memory out of 5000000
 16797 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3728 words of font info for 25 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1328 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 52i,4n,58p,10426b,194s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Error 256 (driver return code) generating output;
file Untitled.pdf may not be valid.
```

Comment: Please show the log of that MWE.

Comment: Could you check the contents of the directory? I get this error message: `xdvipdfmx:fatal: Cannot proceed without the font: /Library/Fonts/Microsoft/Curlz MT Output file removed.` You can see my directory listing in [this paste](http://pastebin.com/Ky34MpYS) - the problem "fonts" are 0 bytes....

Comment: Update: although these "0 byte" files (as reported by terminal via `ls -l`) [show a file-size](http://i.stack.imgur.com/S1f1t.png) in Finder. See also: "[How do I convert a suitcase font?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/8455/136150)" on AskDifferent.SE.

Comment: I checked the directory (see my OP) I get the same result as you: notice how the font Curlz MT does not have a suffix in your directory? Neither does Calisto MT etc. If you'd like me to check for something dofferent can you specify what you want me to look for? My Calisto MT is size 320kb.

Comment: Looks like [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/200074/136150) offers some help if you're desperate to use that exact font. Otherwise, a lot easier to use an acceptable substitute!

Comment: I think you're right, i.e., when trying to work with Microsoft one must use workarounds - one of the reasons I use LaTeX! I'm not desperate and will substitute.